# Forward user after authentication of Google Device

Tags: rest, api, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I have users that link their Google suite account using the [OAuth2ForDevices](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices) approach. After linking the account to the device I would like to forward the user to another page with instructions instead of leaving them at the generic google page "Success! Device connected".

This is the current flow:

**1) Grab device_code and user_code** from POST to URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code

```
curl -X POST \
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=<hidden>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar'
```

**response**

```
{
  "device_code": "ab-cdef...",
  "user_code": "ABCD-ABCD",
  "expires_in": 1800,
  "interval": 5,
  "verification_url": "https://www.google.com/device"
}
```

if i append parameters like **foo=bar** or **forward_url=** the response is still the same as above.

**redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080** it results in an error, so this parameter is obviously recognised.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Invalid redirect URI"
}
```

The problem does not seem to be the URL since the following request works fine: **i managed t**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

2) Let user confirm verification_url (https://www.google.com/device)

3) "Success! Device connected"

I have tried with a bunch of domains and URL:s that has been confirmed in both google search console and added to domain verification in https://console.cloud.google.com

Worth mentioning*: I noticed that Google Cloud Platform behaves in a strange way, removing earlier verified domains -- when I'm adding new domains: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification?project=&pli=1&authuser=1

My theories: 
1) It's simply not possible to add a redirect_uri when using the [OAuth2ForDevices](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices) approach.
2) There is a bug* in Google Cloud Platform that displays me domains but this is cached data.

*[Buggy?? Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ofxs.png)

Comment: Please check the [document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/verify-domain-name) for your domain name verification. Morevoer, please note that only the user account that has verified ownership of the domain name can deploy the API initially.